# Java Switch statement not recognising method-only says user does not exist but does not recognise user

Tags: java, arrays, search, methods, switch-statement

I am currently implementing a java social network which stores certain details such as names and friends. I want to use a function where you can search by last name and it will either recognise it and say that the user already exists, or it will say that the user does not exist. I have used a method and a switch statement to run it; however, it only says that the user does not exist, even though I have matched the username exactly. I had edited it and then it told me that the user did exist, even when they didn't.

EDIT: AS REQUESTED, HERE IS THE WHOLE CLASS:

package CourseworkDraft;

```
/**
 * Created by User on 07/06/2014.
 */


//Demo template program for SWITCH

import java.util.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class SwitchTemplate {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int option;
        int maxSize = 100;
        ArrayInObs arr = new ArrayInObs(maxSize);

        int maxSize2 = 100;
        ArrayInObs arr2 = new ArrayInObs(maxSize2);
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList<String>();








        String lastName;
        String firstName, emailAddress, username, education, homeLocation, countries, favouriteSite, occupation, status,searchName;
        int age = 0;


        ArrayList a1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList a2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList a3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList a4 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList a5 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList a6 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList a7 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList a8 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList a9 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList a10 = new ArrayList<String>();


        a1.add("Paul");
        a1.add("Brian");
        a1.add("Harry");
        a1.add("Simon");
        a1.add("Frank");

        a2.add("Paul");
        a2.add("Harry");
        a2.add("Frank");

        a3.add("Tom");
        a3.add("Frank");
        a3.add("Jim");
        a3.add("Al");
        a3.add("Marty");

        a4.add("Jerry");
        a4.add("Frank");
        a4.add("Bob");
        a4.add("Harry");
        a4.add("Al");
        a4.add("Fred");


        a5.add("Bob");
        a5.add("Frank");
        a5.add("David");
        a5.add("Simon");
        a5.add("Johnny");
        a5.add("Al");
        a5.add("Jim");
        a5.add("Louise");
        a5.add("Claire");

        a6.add("Bob");
        a6.add("Harry");
        a6.add("Frank");

        a7.add("Jim");
        a7.add("Bob");

        a8.add("Bob");
        a8.add("Claire");
        a8.add("Louise");
        a8.add("Jim");
        a8.add("Al");

        a9.add("Bob");
        a9.add("Jason");
        a9.add("Frank");

        a10.add("Jim");
        a10.add("Al");
        a10.add("Bob");


        Set s = new HashSet<String>();
        s.addAll(a1);
        s.addAll(a2);
        s.addAll(a3);
        s.addAll(a4);
        s.addAll(a5);
        s.addAll(a6);
        s.addAll(a7);
        s.addAll(a8);
        s.addAll(a9);
        s.addAll(a10);


        ArrayList b1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList b2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList b3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList b4 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList b5 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList b6 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList b7 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList b8 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList b9 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList b10 = new ArrayList<String>();


        b1.add("golf");
        b1.add("football");
        b1.add("darts");
        b1.add("tennis");
        b1.add("pets");

        b2.add("pets");
        b2.add("travel");
        b2.add("school");
        b2.add("football");
        b2.add("golf");
        b2.add("sleeping");
        b2.add("tennis");

        b3.add("sleeping");
        b3.add("football");


        b4.add("football");
        b4.add("rugby");
        b4.add("the beach");
        b4.add("pubs");


        b5.add("football");
        b5.add("pubs");
        b5.add("history");
        b5.add("sleeping");


        b6.add("football");
        b6.add("golf");
        b6.add("swimming");


        b7.add("cycling");
        b7.add("golf");
        b7.add("football");


        b8.add("internet");
        b8.add("travel");


        b9.add("going home");
        b9.add("finishing coursework");
        b9.add("cycling");


        b10.add("pubs");
        b10.add("dancing");
        b10.add("walking");
        b10.add("football");


        Set t = new HashSet<String>();

        t.addAll(b1);
        t.addAll(b2);
        t.addAll(b3);
        t.addAll(b4);
        t.addAll(b5);
        t.addAll(b6);
        t.addAll(b7);
        t.addAll(b8);
        t.addAll(b9);
        t.addAll(b10);

        {



            arr.insert(" Barry,", " John,", 24, " myemail123@gmail.com", a1, b1, " JohnB", " school of Life ", " Newry", " Japan, Germany ", " bbc.co.uk", " CEO ", " Time for a break! " );
            arr.insert(" Keenan,", " Alan,", 59, " myemail123@hotmail.com", a2, b2, " AlanK", " James Woods High ", " London", " France, USA ", " facebook.com", " Banker", " Yay! Another Bonus ");
            arr.insert(" Flanagan,", " Davy,", 37, " myemail123@msn.com", a3, b3, " DavyF", " Buddy Cianci Junior High ", " Los Angeles", " UAE, Russia " ," reuters.de", " Civil Servant", " Think I'll pull a sickie. ");
            arr.insert(" McEvoy,", " Paul,", 37, " myemail@yahoo.com", a4, b4, " PaulM", " Springfield Elementary ", " Shanghai", " Taiwan, Australia ", " hotmail.com", " Lawyer", " Come back ambulance! ");
            arr.insert(" Yang,", " Yesica,", 43, " myemail@live.co.uk", a5, b5, " YesicaY", " Byker Grove", " Capetown ", " Canada, Poland ", " randomfacts.net", " Doctor", " I'm sick ");
            arr.insert(" Labb,", " Vanessa,", 21, " myemail123@blueyonder.co.uk", a6, b6, " VanessaL", " GrangeHill ", " Paris", " Norway, Switzerland ", " youtube.com", " Teacher", " Yummy breakfast! ");
            arr.insert(" Stubbs,", " Kate,", 29, " myemail@btinternet.com", a7, b7, " KateS", " Bayside High ", " Moscow", " North Korea, Pakistan ", " nintendo.com", " Interpreter", " Anything good on TV today?");
            arr.insert(" Croall,", " Josh,", 72, " myemail123@gmx.de", a8, b8, " JoshC", " Starfleet Academy ", " Berlin", " China, Iran ", " stackoverflow.com", " Sales Rep", " Just booked trip to Egypt!");
            arr.insert(" Valero,", " Jose,", 22, " myemail@hotmail.co.nz", a9, b9, " JoseV", " Tom Landry Middle School ", " Taipei", " Turkey, South Africa ", " google.com", " Developer", " Back from the gym! ");
            arr.insert(" Islam,", " Salma,", 18, " myemail@weibo.cn", a10, b10, " SalmaI", " Summer Heights High ", " Sydney", " Brazil, Mexico ", " linkedin.com", " Journalist", " Breaking news.. ");


            System.out.println("Welcome to Red social ");
            System.out.println("Please Select An Option: ");
            System.out.println("1. Display all user details");
            System.out.println("2. Register an account ");
            System.out.println("3. Display users by alphabetical surname");
            System.out.println("4. Search for a user by surname ");
            System.out.println("5. Search for friend recommendations ");
            System.out.println("6. Check status times ");
            System.out.println("7. Add a new hobby ");
            System.out.println("8. Search for hobby recommendations ");
            System.out.println("9. Edit your account details ");
            System.out.println("10. Add a new friend ");
            System.out.println("11. Delete your account ");
            System.out.println("12. Birthday reminders ");


            option = input.nextInt();
            String searchUserexist;
            searchUserexist = input.nextLine();
            Person exists;
            String surname;
            exists = arr.findLast(searchUserexist);
            if (exists != null)
            {
                System.out.println("This UserSocialNetworkCW.User Already Has An Account Registered In The System ");
            } else











            switch (option) {
                case 1:
                    arr.displayA();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
                    firstName = input.next();

                    System.out.print("Enter last name: ");
                    lastName = input.next();

                    System.out.print("Enter your age: ");
                    age = input.nextInt();

                    System.out.print("Enter email: ");
                    emailAddress = input.next();


                    System.out.print("Enter username: ");
                    username = input.next();

                    System.out.print("Enter education: ");
                    education = input.next();

                    System.out.print("Enter hometown: ");
                    homeLocation = input.next();

                    System.out.print("Enter countries visited: ");
                    countries = input.next();

                    System.out.print("Enter favourite website: ");
                    favouriteSite = input.next();

                    System.out.print("List your occupation: ");
                    occupation = input.next();

                    System.out.print("Add a status: ");
                    status = input.next();


                    arr.insert(lastName , firstName, age, emailAddress, null, null, username, education, homeLocation, countries, favouriteSite, occupation, status);
                    arr.displayA();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    arr.insertionSort();
                    System.out.println("Arranged by alphabetical surname: ");
                    arr.displayA();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.print("Please Enter The User's Last Name: ");
                    surname = input.next();
                    exists = arr.findLast(surname);
                    if (exists != null)

                    {
                        exists.displayPerson();
                        System.out.println(" This User Already Has An Account Registered In The System" + surname);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("The User You Entered Does Not Exist " + surname);
                    }

                    break;
                case 5:
                    for (int i = 0; i < a2.size(); i++) {
                        if (!a3.contains(a2.get(i))) {
                            list.add(a2.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < a3.size(); i++) {
                        if (!a2.contains(a3.get(i))) {
                            list.add(a3.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("You are not currently friends with : " + list);
                    System.out.print("You may want to add: ");
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                        System.out.print((String) list.get(i) + " ");
                    }
                    break;
                case 6:
                    java.util.Date statustime;
                    statustime = new Date();
                    System.out.println("Time of status " + new Timestamp(statustime.getTime()));
                    break;
                case 7:
                    b2 = new ArrayList<String>();
                    b2.add("swimming");
                    System.out.print("You now like " + b2);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    for (int j = 0; j < b2.size(); j++) {
                        if (!b1.contains(b2.get(j))) {
                            list2.add(b2.get(j));
                        }
                    }
                    for (int j = 0; j < b1.size(); j++) {
                        if (!b2.contains(b1.get(j))) {
                            list2.add(b1.get(j));
                        }

                    }
                    System.out.println("  You do not currently like these pages : " + list2);
                    System.out.print(" You may want to like the following pages: ");
                    for (int j = 0; j < list2.size(); j++) {
                        System.out.print((String) list2.get(j) + " ");
                    }
                    break;
                case 9:
                    System.out.println("dragon");
                    break;
                case 10:
                    a2 = new ArrayList<String>();
                    a2.add("Stephen");
                    System.out.print("You have now added " + a2);
                    break;
                case 11:
                    System.out.print(" Delete Your Account");
                    System.out.print(" Enter your last name: ");
                    lastName = input.next();


                   // arr.deleteUser(lastName);
                    if (lastName != null)

                    {
                        System.out.println("Your Account Was Deleted " + lastName + " Sorry you had to go!");
                        firstName=null;
                        lastName=null;
                        age= 0;
                        emailAddress=null;
                        username=null;
                        education=null;
                        homeLocation=null;
                        countries=null;
                        favouriteSite=null;
                        occupation=null;
                        status=null;


                        arr.insert(lastName , firstName, age, emailAddress, null, null, username, education, homeLocation, countries, favouriteSite, occupation, status);

                        System.out.println("Registered Users ");
                        arr.displayA();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("This user does not exist " + lastName);
                    }
                    break;
                case 12:

                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Oops, something went wrong, please choose an option between 1-12");
                    break;


            }


        }


    }
```

This is the method:

```
 public Person findLast (String searchName)
    {

        int i;
        for(i=0;i<nElms;i++)
            if(a[i].getLast().equals(searchName))
                break;
        if(i==nElms)
            return null;
        else




return a[i];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: I have spent the last 2 days trying to fix it and I have edited everything. The debugger on Intellij is not help at all-this is all is says: "Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:60938', transport: 'socket'"

Comment: `arr` is of some type, and that's the important one, not the boring input logic after `case 2`. Full code of arr's class please!

Comment: I have updated the code as requested.

Comment: If that's all the debugger says, then you aren't using it right. You  have to *interact* with it. The debugger isn't some magical thing that fixes all your problems when you run it. [This](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/debugging.html) might be of some help to get you started.

Comment: I can't help noticing the `package CourseworkDraft;` line that you left out of the quoted block of code.

Answer (score 0):

Does your code compile successfully?  Are there errors?  Warnings?

You should probably start by trying to learn how to use your chosen development environment.

You can also try commenting-out lines until you get back to something that **does** run.  Something like:

```
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

It might have been a mistake to edit your code before pasting here: if you don't understand what you're doing, then you're just as likely to add/remove bugs by doing that.  On the other hand, it is an **excellent** idea to trim your code down to a concise example that exhibits the same problem -- see my earlier comment about removing code.

Having said that (which has surely been said here on StackOverflow a million times, and probably better than I've said it), here is a list of obvious errors in the code you have pasted in the original question:

1. It doesn't compile All code must exist inside a class and method.
2. What class and method does your first snippet of code exist inside?
3. The variable `input` is not declared anywhere.  What is it?
4. The variable `arr` is not declared anywhere.  What is it?
5. What is the definition of `arr.insert()` and `arr.display()`?
6. You do not have a `break` statement at the end of `case 2:`, before
   `case 3:`; is this intentional?
7. You do not have a closing brace at the end of the `switch`
   statement.

A really easy way to simplify this code down to just the crux of it would be to remove all the code that deals with any of the fields other than the `last name`.  All those fields just add bulk to your code snippet -- probably without affecting how it works (or how it fails).

Cheers.

Comment: I am using objects so it is difficult after so much to just try line by line. I have included the code as requested. There are no error warnings. arr.insert is to store the contents of array of objects and also to insert them. arr.display is used to show the user lists and also to arrange in alphabetical order, both of which work. It is just the searching that is giving me trouble and without it, I can't get the delete or edit until search is resolved.